# Flutter: async, await

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await, future

```
void getLocation() async {
  await location.getCurrentLocation();
  *latlng* = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);}
```

.
.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       GoogleMap(
         onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
         mapType: MapType.normal,
         initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
           target: *latlng*,
           zoom: 14.4746,
         ),
       ),
```

I want to use latlng in widget. However, 'target == null' is output asynchronously. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are getting no answers this is usually due to the fact that you have not asked in a very clear and detailed way. Please add more information then you will have a better impact.

Comment: Use if else, check if latlng is null then show loader until latlng get after latlng receive pass it to map

Answer (score 0):

usually what we do is declare a Boolean for example `coordAvbl = flase;`

and on running the async function of getting the location you use a `setState` to change to the boolean from `false` to `true` this will rebuild the whole widget tree

and for this work you need use a ternary operator in your in your `Scaffold()`

So this is how you go

```
void getLocation() async {
  await location.getCurrentLocation();
  *latlng* = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
   setState(() {
      coordAvbl = true;
     
    });
}
```

and modify your Scaffold as

```
override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       coordAvbl ? GoogleMap(
         onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
         mapType: MapType.normal,
         initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
           target: *latlng*,
           zoom: 14.4746,
         ),
       ) : Container(),
    ]
```

I guess you have missed some Brackets but this how you do so if the `coordAvbl = true` then it will show the map I guess or else it will show an empty container.

fell free to comment if you get any errors

regards,
roshan